# Allow user's defined properties on a class in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I'm working with boost on a project and I would like to use the [Bundled Properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) mechanism on a class Foo. This is to allow the user to add data like a struct to the class.

Actually, Foo is a class used in similar ways to the edges on a graph in the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/). Foo needs to contains user defined datas (tags, IDs, ...) that the user can handle through visitors during algorithms process for example.

However I was not able to understand how to add this capability to my class Foo with meta programming. Could you explain me some design patterns to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is simple.
The hosting class take as a template parameter the hosted one.

Once it has it, it just derive from the latter:

```
template <class T>
template class Host : public T
{
};
```

As the rules of inheritance specifies, all public members are accessible from the deriven class.

If you want to chain more properties, use multiply inheritance.

Simple and awesome, right?

Comment: Yeh it looks nice, I will start implementing things this way. However, is there no overhead ? I am not sure about time as there is nothing virtual but about space with padding for example ?

Comment: How efficient it with padding is up to compiler decision, since this class is not POD(plain old data). If you really want fast data access, try external properties(like used in boost graph). Their advantage is that they follow data oriented design. Also, please upvote me if I was helpful.

Comment: Can I allow the user to not add datas to Host without the cost of an empty struct ?

Comment: @Ronan Accoording to C++ standards, again, the size and the position that the compiler choose for derived class is up to the compiler decision. However, all the compilers I familiar with does not save place for empty derrived class, since it's pointless, so you can sleep well :-)

Comment: Yup, I will keep studying the boost implementation for it, just to know